# Resolving ModuleNotFoundError when executing from file

Tags: python

I have installed the pyserial module using pip3. Importing that module and executing (copy and pasting) the program line by line in the IDLE shell works fine but running a file (with IDLE) results in the ModuleNotFoundError.

My python version is 3.7.3 on MacOS 10.14.5

I have compared the sys.version, sys.path and sys.executable.
sys.version is

```py
"3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]"
```

sys.executable is

```py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

sys.path is

```py
['', '/Users/edidos/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

There are no differences except for sys.path[0] referencing the file location when run from file.

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
print()
print(sys.version)
print()
print(sys.executable)

import serial.tools.list_ports
ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):
        print("{}: {} [{}]".format(port, desc, hwid))
```

Here is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edidos/Projecte/PythonRPLidar/serial.py", line 9, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
  File "/Users/edidos/Projecte/PythonRPLidar/serial.py", line 9, in <module>
    import serial.tools.list_ports
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial.tools'; 'serial' is not a package
```

Comment: use  `from serial import tool` instead of `import serial.tools.list_ports` use `list_ports` as `tools.list_port`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Turns out I named the file serial.py wich interfered with the import serial (duh)

Can't help being an idiot sometimes.